# how to upload data from a List to a datagridview columns

Tags: c#

Try to unload the words from the list into the table, where in one column of the letters and in another amount from the entered letters. As I understand it is necessary to break the word from the collection into single characters `.Distinct()`:

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();

    list.Add(txtInput.Text);
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var letter in list.Distinct())
    {
        Table.Rows.Add(); 
        var count = list.Count(chr => chr == letter);
        Table.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = letter;
        Table.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = count;   
        i++;
    }           
}
```

Comment: It works with a string, but it became interesting as with a list

Comment: Still not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here. You are passing a string from the textbox & adding it to a list & displaying that to a datagridview